# How do I draw mind maps seamlessly with touch screen only?

Tags: applications, drawing

Desktop software such as MindManager and FreeMind allows you to easily draw [Mind Maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind_map). But their interface rely on much keyboard shortcuts that doesn't work (well) on Android virtual keyboard. Is there a way to draw such mind maps seamlessly with touch screen only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been using the app Thinking Space. Certainly not as efficient but good if i want to map a quick idea out.

Comment: [Thinking Space](http://www.thinkingspace.net) is what I currently use. I've recently upgraded to Thinking Space Pro to get the additional attachment/linking feature. However, its touchscreen interface doesn't yet feel fully baked. The on screen menu/submenu doesn't make full use of my Viewpad WVGA screen real estate. The quick tool bar has a gesture button, but gestures are still being revised. However I agree this is my best choice so far, so I'm marking this answered.

Comment: [Thinking Space on Android Market](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.thinkingspace)

Answer (score 2):

Try mind map memo. Easy to add new branches with a simple swipe but not as powerful as Thinking Space.

Comment: Positive first look at [Mind Map Memo](http://www.takahicorp.com/android/mindmapmemo.html). The screenshots looks nice, since the nodes can connect at four sides (Thinking Space basically connects on left and right sides only). But first feel of the touch screen interface is a bit negative, zoom is only via a slide bar (Thinking Space has multi touch pinch zoom). I'll try it out more ...

Comment: [Mind Map Memo on Android Market](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.takahicorp.MindMap)